# How can I delete a review in the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

I want to delete or at least modify a review in a program at Ubuntu software center. I was wondering if there is any way I can do that since I logged in with the account I had written the review , and there was no option to modify my review.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

If you check the bottom-right corner of your review, there is an `Edit` and a `Delete` button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Evandro, but there is a problem.
I did not had ubuntu in my PC for like 1-2 months, and I just returned to Ubuntu. I downloaded again that program and I saw I had a review written there, so I wanted to delete it, I was trying to see where I could write a review, and then I remembered I have to download the program first to be allowed to write a review, so did I, I downloaded the program again and I clicked "Log in" after clicking "Write a review" so I log in there.
But, although in "write a review" I can see the same name with the review already been written, It....

Comment: ..... does not say " (That's you)" and does not have any delete / edit button

Comment: @user97891 You need to log in to the software center for it to recognize you. In order to write a review, you needed an account. Make sure you are logged in to that account.

Comment: I just added a review and there is no such option visible, 22.04...